# Introducing a custom configuration to NodeJS

Tags: node.js, rest, weblogic

I am working in a nodeJS project. It doesn't access the database directly whereas all the required information are retrieved through Rest end points  which is hosted in weblogic. I have a requirement to introduce another REST endpoint do a user validation check and validation should happen based on the value in a configuration file.

e.g Configuration File will have a property EnableUserNameCheck=True.

If the value set to true user validation happens if not it will not be taken place.  The reason to introduce this switch is internal implementation of the user validation service has some external dependencies. If these services are down application engineer can make the switch off and allow the users to continue.

Question :-

As there are two HTTP calls involved, 1) Browser to NodeJS Server 2) NodeJs to RestService in WebLogic, Is it correct to have this configuration value in NodeJS. Then if the value is set to false there is no need to make the Rest Service Call at all. If I include this switch in REST Service then regardless of the switch is ON or OFF Service call have to be made. I want to know whether introducing a custom config value as above is a good practice. What are the disadvantages of having a switch in NodeJS side related to my context

Frequency of the config value being changed will be very minimal.

If adding a config value to NodeJS is a good approach given the above situation, please direct me to some materials which I can go through

Comment: What have you already tried?  When I did a web search of "nodejs config", "nodejs global config" and "nodejs global variables" I found a good deal of information...much of it on this site.

Comment: Are you allowed to restart NodeJS to update inner config state, or you need to switch state on the fly?

Comment: I am new to nodejs and trying to understand what is the best way to introduce the configuration switch. In order to reflect the change in the configuration I think server needs to be restarted. Isn't it? or can it be done without a restart. What I primarily trying understand is what is the best way to handle this situation.

Comment: Also the other question that I have is; if the config value needs to be changed in production how to do it. Because by then the files are minified and already deployed

Comment: My question has been voted minus. This is not right. When a programmer has a concern if that cannot be posted here and cant expect a fair answer then it is useless. For someone this might not be an interesting question but for some it is very important to know what that is.